# Se cierra Visual Studio cuando abro un archivo o pagina aspx

Tags: asp.net

En cierto proyecto utilizo un formulario aspx con el cual veo e imprimo reportes de diferentes tipos, el problema es que cuando selecciono la pestaña o el archivo para trabajar con él se traba visual studio y se reinicia solo, debo aclarar que es el único archivo con el cual me pasa esto.

PD: También utilizo reportviewer, no se si tiene algo que ver.

Comment: VIsual Studio, en qué versión? Yo revisaría que esté generando logs para saber qué pasa [(documentación)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms241272(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 community

Comment: Sí, aplica el generar logs [así](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/log-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019). Con eso ves por qué falla con ese archivo. Prueba, vuelve y edita tu pregunta con lo que encuentres relevante en ese log

Comment: Que Visual tienes instalado y que versión de reportviewer utilizas ?

Comment: hace poco solucioné ese problema actualizando la versión del report viewer

Answer (score 0):

quizas o solucionaste, pero escribo como lo solucione yo por si a alguien le sirve.
Yo lo solucione agregando un nuevo reporte pero con el asistente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

nuevo elemento > Asaistente para informes

Entonces ahi me tiro el error que estaba provocando que el visual studio se reiniciara, en mi caso era que una dll estaba desactualizada,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo fue cosa de actualizar esa dll y me funciono correctamente.

Espero que les sea de ayuda.
Saludos!